# How to overlay a barplot on a stacked barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, geom-bar, stacked

I am trying to overlay a bar plot over a stacked bar plot as you can see in the figure below. Although this is working well the dotted line type does not appear as such in the legend.

[Dotted bar plot on top of stacked barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNqCp.png)

This is my data:

```
data = data.frame(treat=c("min","plus","min","plus"),
                  obs=c(8,7,121,98),
                  type=c("Tare","Tare","Net","Net"))

data2 = data.frame(treat=c("min","plus"),
                   obs=c(20,15),
                   type=c("Sugar","Sugar"))
```

And the code I use to make the graph:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=treat, y=obs, fill = type)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col = "black", width = .75) +
  geom_bar(data = data2, stat="identity", fill = "transparent", col = "black", size = .8, linetype = "dotted", width = .75, show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4", NA),
         limits = c("Tare", "Net", "Sugar"))
```

How do I make the second bar appear with dotted lines in the legend?

Comment: After I added the figure I simplified the code, so the figure does not match exactly with the code, but the idea of what is my problem is still visible

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to have a separate legend for the dotted line?

Comment: No, I want the small square left from 'Sugar' to be with a dotted line

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(treat=c("min","plus","min","plus"),
                  obs=c(8,7,121,98),
                  type=c("Tare","Tare","Net","Net"))

data2 = data.frame(treat=c("min","plus"),
                   obs=c(20,15),
                   type=c("Sugar","Sugar"))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=treat, y=obs, fill = type)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col = "black", width = .75) +
  geom_bar(data = data2, stat="identity", 
           fill = "transparent", col = "black", size = .8, 
           aes(linetype = "dotted"), 
           width = .75, 
           show.legend = T) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4", NA),
                    limits = c("Tare", "Net", "Sugar"),
                    name="type")+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Sugar", values="dotted")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1),
         linetype=guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Not exactly, I want the little square before sugar to be with a dotted line. If that doesn't work your solution is the second best